# how to set the parameter targetURi dynamically in HTTP Proxy Servlet

Tags: java, http, servlets, proxy

Good morning, I decided to create a http proxy servlet because I'm in a network where almost all pages are blocked, there is a firewall that blocks almost all called fortinet.
My idea is to use a server that I have which is not blocked, but on that server only have installed an archive of web applications (glassfish) and want to create a web application that serves me as an intermediary between the pages you wish to visit and my pc and thus navigate freely without restrictions.

So far I have used the [HTTP-Proxy-Servlet project](https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet)

The problem is: apparently only connects to a single web that previously we configure the `web.xml` file with the parameter `targetUri`

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>targetUri</param-name>
    <param-value>http://solrserver:8983/solr</param-value>
</init-param>
```

How to change this parameter dynamically and navigate as a common and current online proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement a "real" proxy (not just a "fixed URL" one), you need to use the `getRequestURL` method to get the real URL which was requested.

For example, in HTTP-Proxy-Servlet, when he writes:

```
String proxyRequestUri = rewriteUrlFromRequest(servletRequest);
```

You can write:

```
String proxyRequestUri = servletRequest.getRequestURL().toString();
```

I'm not saying that's the only change you'll have to make, but it's a start.

Alternatively, you could reconstruct the URL using the other getters from the request:

- `getScheme` (http, https etc)
- `getServerName`
- `getServerPort` (which might be 80)
- `getRequestURI`
- `getQueryString` or `getParameterNames` / `getParameterValues`

(For some reason, when you type "java proxy servlet" into Google, the first result that comes up is HTTP-Proxy-Servlet. However it's not actually that useful IMO, because it only directs to a fixed URL as you mentioned.)